# Skype no longer recognises camera

Tags: skype, webcam, logitech

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and I've just updated Skype. The microphone of my Logitech C615  webcam still works. The camera still works in Cheese and guvcview, but is no longer recognized in Skype

Answer (score 3):

I just had the same problem. I used `sudo modprobe uvcvideo` to reconnect/reinitialize (?) the camera.

Comment: This just works for me on ubuntu 16.04 thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, and I have reverted Skype to previous version 8.11.0.4 which is working fine.

In Synaptic menu: Package => Force version

In Terminal: `sudo apt-get install skypeforlinux=8.11.0.4`

Comment: Thank you, that essentially fixed it for me. When I "downgraded" the sound no longer worked, but all I had to do to solve that is change the microphone line in in the Skype "Audio and Video Settings".

Answer (score 2):

You can keep latest Skype version and uninstall `cheese` and its config files.

Uninstall `cheese` and config files:

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove cheese
```

Reinstall `cheese`:

```
sudo apt-get install cheese
```

Reboot your computer

This works perfectly for a Dell Notebook using Ubuntu 16.04 with Skype version = 8.18.0.6 (dual boot)

Comment: This did not help in my case.

Comment: Yep. Removing Cheese did the trick.

Comment: Ubuntu 18.10.  I did the above, video still not showing (microphone fine). In Skype, Audio/video. In the camera section  Selected HD Pro webcam c920 2 identical items, second item enabled video camera (blue light on, on the webcam)

Answer (score 0):

Using preload was the only thing that worked for me on an old camera (USB2.0 webcam) with Ubuntu 18.04, fully updated.

```
LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libv4l/v4l1compat.so /usr/bin/skypeforlinux
```

The link to the full steps is (https://journalxtra.com/linux/skype-video-linux-always-hassle/) if you don't know what preload is.