# Skype Camera No device found

Tags: skype

[image]

I installed Ubuntu 20.04 on MacBook.

I tried different thread of this problem, but I'm not able to solve the problem.
How can I fix this problem so that I can use a camera with Skype.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Skype no longer recognises camera](https://askubuntu.com/questions/994535/skype-no-longer-recognises-camera)

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved the problem.

```
sudo apt install git curl cpio
cd ~/Downloads 
git clone https://github.com/patjak/facetimehd-firmware.git
cd facetimehd-firmware
make clean
make
sudo make install
cd ..
sudo apt install kmod libssl-dev checkinstall
git clone https://github.com/patjak/bcwc_pcie.git
cd bcwc_pcie
make clean
make
sudo make install
sudo depmod
sudo modprobe facetimehd
```

Run the following to check if you have facetimehd.ko:

```
ls /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/extra
# output
facetimehd.ko
```

And add facetimehd to the /etc/modules:

```
sudo vim /etc/modules
```

Open Skype to check if the integrated camera is working.